# Interpreting the velocity vector of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and define
$$c_p(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos 2t &- \sin2t\\\sin2t &\cos2t
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Then the velocity vector $c_p'(0)$ can easily be calculated as
$$c_p'(0) = 2y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big\vert_{c(0)} +  2x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big\vert_{c(0)}.$$

I am able to calculate the velocity vector itself (i.e. $c_p'(0)$), but I am unsure how to think of it. Based on the name, I assume this is saying something like for any curve in $T_p(\mathbb{R}^2)$, at time $t = 0$ the corresponding velocity along $c$ at a point $(x,y)$ is given by $c'(p)$. However this doesn't make sense as the velocity vector acts on an element of $C_p^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I am new to manifolds so it could be that I am incorrectly thinking of the tangent space. More generally, my current interpretation of the differential is that it approximates a particular function between manifolds linearly. The velocity curve is then a differential that takes in as an input $d/dt$. In his book, Lee describes this as

> The velocity vector $\gamma'(t_0)$ is the derivation at $\gamma(t_0)$ obtained by taking the derivative of a function along $\gamma$.

I am not too clear on the physical picture here. What is the correct interpretation of the velocity vector object?

Comment: Waht is the relation between $p$ and $c_p$? Does $p$ have coordinates $x,y$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Sorry I should have specified that. In general we let $p$ be any point on a manifold $M$. The notation $c_p$ means $c(0) = p$ so that the curve "starts at $p$". Since $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ in my example then $p = (x,y)$ for some $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So you mean that the velocity is given by $c'(0)$, not $c'(p)$. The latter makes no sense, as $c$ is a mapping from $\Bbb R$ to your manifold (here, $\Bbb R^2$). Think of it geometrically just as you did in multivariable calculus: It's the tangent vector $(-2y,2x)$ [you lost a sign], which — in derivation language — is as you wrote it [except for the sign].

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes that is correct, thank you for catching the typos. In multivariable calculus I interpret the velocity vector as giving us the rate of change of each component (physically with respect to time). Generalizing this, does the velocity vector of a manifold tell us how the differential changes as we travel across the curve $c$?

Comment: There is no velocity vector of a manifold. Only velocity vector of a curve *in* a manifold. I don’t know what you mean by the differential.

Comment: @TedShifrin The differential is defined as the map $df: T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ induced by the smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds.

Comment: So you’re referring to the differential of the mapping $c$. The relation you need is this: $c’(0) = dc_0(1)$ (where $1$ is the standard basis of $T_0\Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$).

Comment: @TedShifrin So in that sense does the velocity curve tell us how the tangent vectors (i.e. the derivations) are changing as we move along the curve $c$?

Comment: Your language continues to be sloppy. The velocity vector of a curve is giving you a specific tangent vector at each point of the curve. The chain rule tells you that for any function $f$ on $M$ you can compute $df_p(v)$ for any tangent vector $v$ at $p$ by $(f\circ c)’(0)$ for any curve $c$ with $c(0)=p$ and $c’(0)=v$. This is highly useful and important.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry about the sloppy language, I am still trying to wrap my head around some of these concepts. I think I understand it now, the velocity vector of a curve gives us a specific derivation at each point along the curve. Thank you for all your help and patience.

Comment: You're most welcome.